# Getting next and previous document

Tags: mongodb

In a mongo collection I have a list of words (millions words).

```
{word:'a'}
{word:'b'}
{word:'x'}
{word:'y'}
{word:'z'}
```

I need to get lexical adjacents of a word (next and previous). I am looking for most efficient method.

Comment: Is your database somewhat static or is content dynamically added to it rigorously.

Comment: @SushantGupta It's not totally static. But it is read-extensive.

Comment: One hack to the problem is, simply provide with an extra field in db like `word_index` which store a simple lexicographic rank for that word. And then just a simple $in query of [n-1, n, n+1], n being word index would have done it. But its only makes sense had it been your db STATIC. Or even if your db is updated after scheduled intervals, but not dynamically. Because it needs a full table updation for any change in db.

Comment: A variation of the previous proposal is to have db references for each document (one for prev and one for next), therefore after a new document insertion you need to update only two documents (still way to complex, in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply execute two queries?

The first one would look for documents with 'word > "YOURWORD"', sorting by 'word' (asc) with limit 1, then the second one would look for documents with 'word < "YOUTWORD"', sorting by 'word' (desc), again with limit 1.

I guess you've an index on the field, so it should be quite performant.

Here's a code example:

```
var prev = db.words.find({"word": {$gt: "YOURWORD"}}).sort({"word": 1}).limit(1);
var next = db.words.find({"word": {$lt: "YOURWORD"}}).sort({"word": -1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: For a simple feature on a webpage like < previous | curr_page | next > won't it be a unnecessary overhead to do 2 queries. Though having index is a HUGE factor, but issuing a db query must be having some overheads as well. Though I was myself thinking of posting this as my answer only, but then I thought to wait for some sexy solution if there exist any. :P

Comment: @PHPst After an index, sorting is actually very performant. In your case the elements SCANNED after having an index would be just 2. So its a complexity of O(1).

Comment: MongoDB does not guarantee you the order of stored records, therefore you can't rely on static positioning: you need some kind of sorting.
Another (bad) option would be having prev/next db references, that involves a lot of processing during new insertions and updates in order to keep the references updated. And it could still bring consistency problems if your updates are very concurrent.